# Referencing overloaded Java methods in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am wondering how can I reference an overloaded method from Java class in Kotlin.

For example, in the interface `WebClient` there are three get methods:

```
  HttpRequest<Buffer> get(int port, String host, String requestURI);
  HttpRequest<Buffer> get(String host, String requestURI);
  ...
```

In kotlin I want to reference the one with the three parameters:

```
val methodReference : WebClient.(port : Int, host: String?, requestUrl: String?) -> HttpRequest<Buffer> = WebClient::get
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public abstract operator fun get(p0: Int, p1: String!, p2: String!): HttpRequest<Buffer!>! defined in io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient
public abstract operator fun get(p0: String!): HttpRequest<Buffer!>! defined in io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient
public abstract operator fun get(p0: String!, p1: String!): HttpRequest<Buffer!>! defined in io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the same `Buffer` class (and the same `HttpRequest`) class as the function you're referring to?  (It's easy to get confused between classes of the same name in different packages, and the error messages don't always distinguish.)

Comment: @gidds you were right... programmer blindness. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it with default values.

```
val methodReference : WebClient.(port:Int=8080, host:String='host', requestUrl:String='url') -> HttpRequest<Buffer> = WebClient::get
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the reference like this:

```kotlin
val methodReference: WebClient.(Int, String, String) -> HttpRequest<Buffer>? = WebClient::get
```

Comment: It's the same problem.

Comment: @AndreiCiobanu well, it does work for me! check https://imgur.com/a/fiGAYPA which error you're encountering?